# How do I use the Html Slider Control's Value for a Variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Slider Control: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_range_get

```
function generateNumber() {
var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
//Generates a random number from 1-100
var pass = 50;
//Compare number with pass value
if ( randomNum > pass )
```

How do I get the slider control's value to replace 'pass'? eg. User drags slider to ' 30 '. Randomly generated number will be compared to see if higher than 30.

solved thanks!

Comment: for some sort of security. it's best if you just paste your minimal understandable code here. downloading from external site raises such security concerns for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example given your slider has an id "myRange". You can assign it's value like this: `pass = document.getElementById("myRange").value;`